# Anyone know how I can get rid of this error message?

Tags: jquery, html

please take a quick look at this [website](http://tdsoft.se/failed.html)

I get the following error message since it takes time to read in 'parsers.json'. Now to my question, is there a way to get rid of this annoying error message?

```
Line: 46 

Character: 3 

Code: 0 Error

Message: 'readyState' is null or not an object 

URL: http://tdsoft.se/failed.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a JS function which is producing the error. It cannot find the variable 'readyState'

```
var checkState = function(xmlhttp, callback) {
//document.write(xmlhttp.readyState);
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
  // --> failed.html:46Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'readyState' of undefined
    callback();
  } else {
    // Check back again 1 sec later
    setTimeout(checkState, 1000);
  }
};
```

Why the `document.write(xmlhttp.readyState);` is been commented out? Might that be the bug.

Comment: So is there a way to "try/catch" this error, just like in ordinary java, and in that catch just "setTimeout(checkState, 1000);" wait and do nothing? =)

Comment: Yes you can apply the try/catch OR you can also check for the variable like `if(xmlhttp.readyState){ ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would load jQuery and not use its ajax methods.

You can use either [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) to do what you need to do.

My guess the problem with your code is the onreadystatechange is getting fired too quickly, possibly when the parsers.json is cached.

Comment: hehehe I hate when that happens

Answer (score 0):

you should have a look at using the AJAX features of [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) it's a much easier to use and more stable method of making AJAX requests.

Comment: I know, but this didn't work in opera, so I abandoned that =)

Comment: hmm, that's odd. Maybe you should submit a bug report to jQuery http://bugs.jquery.com/newticket